# Is Automotive Culture a duplicate of Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair?

Tags: discussion

I have opened a [new proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/83202/automotive-culture) in Area 51 called Automotive Culture. It is about the fun stuff we do with autos, like racing, off road, rally, restore, customize, show cars, hot rods etc.

I have started a discussion about if ["Is Automotive Culture a duplicate of Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair?"](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19798/is-automotive-culture-a-duplicate-of-motor-vehicle-maintenance-repair)

I would like this proposal if it becomes a site to stay out of the scope of Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair. I am asking that some of you become involved in helping this new proposal achieve that. You can help by discussing what you think at the [is Automotive Culture a duplicate question](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19798/is-automotive-culture-a-duplicate-of-motor-vehicle-maintenance-repair), and as the proposal progresses down voting example questions you believe are in the scope of Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair. Also upvoting if you would like, example questions that fit the proposal and would be off topic here.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I think it is a duplicate, yes. Of the five example questions you have posted, four are linked to modifying cars, which I think is generally considered on-topic here, and the fifth "For an endurance trial or a night navi, are harnesses and roll cages mandatory?" is wholly jurisdiction-specific and so I'd either downvote it or ask for clarification on either site.

Answer (score -1):

I'm agreeing with @NickC here. I think once you get away from the duplicated questions from here, most everything you are looking at question wise will most likely be leaning towards the opinion realm. Most any question which is about driving technique is going to almost always draw opinion.

Also, I believe there is another proposal out there right now which is something very similar to what your proposal is ... [Cars](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/84505/cars) would also be in competition with your proposal. They only have 5 followers (at this time) with 12 questions, so not much ahead of your's.